# Java / Spring: How to Hook Into Request For Authentication

Tags: java, spring, authentication

I am working on a JAXRS web service and I need to put in place both authentication and authorization.  The authorization part is easy, but I'm trying to get my head around how to authenticate.  Mind you, I know what authentication is, but I am looking for an implementation, or to create my own.  I have read about Spring security, but a lot of those solutions involve XML config, and I'm going for Zero XML configuration.  I know its a tall order.  But so far so good, up until authentication.  Here is my Jetty starter:

```
package com.example.app.web;

import com.example.app.context.Config;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;

public class JettyStarter {

    public static void main( final String[] args ) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        final ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(new CXFServlet());
        final ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.addServlet(servletHolder, "/app/*");
        context.addEventListener(new ContextLoaderListener());
        context.setInitParameter("contextClass", AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class.getName());
        context.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", Config.class.getName());
        server.setHandler(context);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

My Config class is similarly XML free:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.app")
public class Config { 

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public SpringBus cxf() {
        return new SpringBus();
    }

    @Bean
    public JaxRsApiApplication jaxRsApiApplication() {
        return new JaxRsApiApplication();
    }

// etc...

}
```

Now I want to hook into some kind of authentication phase, and I don't mind rolling my own authentication if it means not programming in XML.  But how do I inform Spring that I want to check on authentication before the api routes gets hit? Does this question make sense?

As an added complexity, routes like a health check do not need authentication, whereas routes that do real things, eg create accounts, update user info, etc, do need authentication.  In the perfect scenario I have nginx sitting in front of my Java application server (Jetty), and reverse proxy as needed.  I assume I can have nginx tell me everything about the request, including cookies, so this should be possible.  Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Spring security 3.2 will have full java configuration support.  It is not yet GA, but it should be soon.  http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/

Comment: Spring security can be configured in Java though it can be quite verbose, especially if you're using the ACL sub-module.  What do you mean by "authentication device"?  Can you elaborate on what authentication you are doing?  BASIC, Oauth, DIGEST, etc...?  This could be effectuated in theory by a servlet filter, or a spring filter but you're pretty light on details.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Nicholas!

Comment: Taylor, let me give you some more info, this is a client side mvc app, angular, jquery etc.  The server side is json SOA, and a few velocity templates.  The templates for the actual pages are also served from the server side. Im open to basic, oauth and digest.  I think what you mentioned about a servlet filter or spring filter, but I have yet to code either.  Would that be something day for the Jetty starter, or the spring container?  Sounds like either could work.  Users will log in with a user pass, and stay logged in until they logout, or some timeout is reached.

Comment: Does this sound like a good case for basic, oauth or digest to you?  Thank you for the detailed feedback!

Comment: It's hard to say as a lot of it will be based on your requirements.  Basic is simple but also easily hacked if not over https.  Oauth can be quite complex, and there's 2-legged vs. 3-legged which solve different subsets of problems.  A servlet filter would be something you configure with jetty (one typically defines these in the web.xml).  Spring filters allow you to hook up spring managed beans as servlet filters.  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-container-config

Comment: Thanks Taylor, though I don't readily see how to add the filter. If you have time would you be willing to provide a solution for the above setup?